# Find the stationary points and monotony of $y = \frac 13 x^3 - x^2 - 3x$?

Tags: derivatives

$$y = \dfrac{1}{3} x^3 - x^2 - 3x$$

I know that I have to equate the first derivative of the function in order to get the stationary points, that makes perfect sense to me. But how do I find the monotony intervals ?

Please help :D

Comment: Monotony intervals are the intervals where the derivative is positive or negative. I.e. $y'>0$ or $y'<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivative is $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$. If we set it equal to zero, we have $$(x-3)(x+1)=0.$$ Your stationary points are $x=-1$ and $x=3$. To find the monotony intervals, consider doing a number line test, like this: [image]

Test each region with a number. So from $(-\infty,-1)$, plug in, say $x=-2$ (you could choose any $x=a$ for $a < -1$), into your $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and find the value. If the number is negative, put a $-$ in the region. If the number is positive, put a $+$. Repeat this for regions $(-1,3)$ and $(3,\infty)$.

If your interval contains a $+$, then that interval is incrasing. Similarly, if your interval contains a $-$, then that interval is decrasing.